# Set GPS Location in Emulator using Android Studio

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-studio

In eclipse you can set a GPS location for the emulator using:

> Select Window > Show View > Other > Emulator Control.
>
> In the Emulator Control panel, enter GPS coordinates under Location
>   Controls as individual lat/long coordinates, with a GPX file for route
>   playback, or a KML file for multiple place marks. (Be sure that you
>   have a device selected in the Devices panel—available from Window >
>   Show View > Other > Devices.)

Is this possible in android studio?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-tips.html)

> If you want to debug your app with the Android Debug Monitor, you can
>   launch it by clicking Monitor  in the toolbar.

Comment: Thanks, every time I clicked on the monitor I had [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17424533/android-ddms-monitor-does-not-start-if-user-profile-contains-a-space-in-it) problem. Managed to fix it by running as admin.  Now I can see the emulator control.

Comment: I dont see any way to set anything on the DDMS screen (other than screen capture, and system information on the left).  Where are they?

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to work in the latest Android Studio 1.0.2. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 25):

```
Tools --> Android --> Android Device Monitor
```

If your emulator is running and not offline, you will get window like in eclipse to set Emulator control.

Comment: I don't have an Android submenu in the Tools menu. Using Studio 4.3.1.

Answer (score 8):

On the Right Side of Your Android Emulator Where (Power Button ,Speaker , Camera  etc Sign are given Find Three Dot Sign(...) at the last of that column. click on that  then Click on location  and Set the Latitude and longitude

Comment: Yes, it works (Android Studio). Due to, do not forget to restart the emulator.