# Set GPS location in Android Studio while debugging app

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, location, adb

(Preface: I have already seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18972114/set-gps-location-in-emulator-using-android-studio), but it doesn't address setting the location while debugging the app.  Opening "Android Device Monitor" closes the ADB connection to the debugger itself.)

I am trying to debug an application that monitors for location changes.  The issue that I have is that I can't figure out how to run the debugger and set the location using `adb geo fix ...` at the same time.

I have tried running the command in the Android Studio "Debug" -> "Console" tab, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

How can I set the location while still remaining connected in the debugger?

Comment: Have you tried the emulator console (telnet into `localhost:5554`)?

Comment: @CommonsWare I was afraid that doing that would mess up the connection into Android Studio also, but it does seem to work. It's a shame that there's no built-in way in Android Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, I did this using [Android GPS Emulator](https://github.com/dpdearing/android-gps-emulator), a Java program which runs on the computer and sends location updates over ADB.

Answer (score 4):

1- go to plugins and look for GPS emulator, and install it then start the emulator from Tools--> Android---> Android device monitor
then find you desired location long and lat (search google for any website that gives you the lang lat for your city, google: get lang lat websites) and send them to the android emulator.

2- or fastes way if android emulator is running On the Right Side of Your Android Emulator Where (Power Button ,Speaker , Camera etc Sign are given Find Three Dot Sign(...) at the last of that column. click on that then Click on location and Set the Latitude and longitude

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should install application that can set fake gps location like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fakegps.mock run it first, then run your app.

Comment: I can't do that, because I need to have the location change several times *while my app is running* in order to test it properly.