# Android studio issue, application cannot be run, Something rejects my device from running the app

Tags: android

have already applied device change, cable change , Android studio restarting , System restarting , adb restart and killing etc nothing helped
One of my log file in sdk tools folder gives this output:

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-09-10 00:38:33.745
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.io.IOException: The folder "C:\Users\Mehran%20khan.android\monitor-workspace.metadata" is read-only.
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.BasicLocation.lock(BasicLocation.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.BasicLocation.set(BasicLocation.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.BasicLocation.set(BasicLocation.java:137)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.monitor.MonitorApplication.start(MonitorApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)

[image]
the log file shows eclipse problems every where while i have not installed eclipse at all.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein I edited the question , when i tries to open Tools->Android->Android Device Monitor it gives message An error has occured , please see the log file at sdk->tools->lib->monitor-x86-64->configuration->1441870697599.log             and the log file result have i given in the question

Answer (score 0):

Other post had gave a solution for the problem, according to [post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30473371/unable-to-open-ddms-in-android-studio-mysterious-eclipse-error-pops-up) and
[post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17424533/android-ddms-monitor-does-not-start-if-user-profile-contains-a-space-in-it/18876626#18876626), your problem is caused by %20 in your name:

```
The folder "C:\Users\Mehran%20khan.android\monitor-workspace.metadata" is read-only. at
```

You can follow the steps:

1. Open a command prompt as administrator. (shift+ctrl+(enter or click)
   on the icon will do this)
2. `cd C:\Users`
    `mklink /d "Mehran%20khan.android" "Mehran khan.android"`
3. Launch Android Studio and Sync the project

I have not tried the solution because I have not come across the problem, if it works, please let me know~