# unable to open android device monitor

Tags: android-device-monitor

I am using android studio. I need to store data in SQLite, but I am unable to open android device monitor.

Error msg:

Check 1473682358409.log.

1473682358409.Log:

!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\UserName.android\monitor-workspace.metadata.lock (Access is denied)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:316)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.(RandomAccessFile.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.Locker_JavaNio.lock(Locker_JavaNio.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.BasicLocation.lock(BasicLocation.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.BasicLocation.set(BasicLocation.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.BasicLocation.set(BasicLocation.java:137)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.monitor.MonitorApplication.start(MonitorApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)

Answer (score 1):

Try Running Android Studio As administrator . right Click the SDK icon and choose "Run As Administratotr"  .. if it failed try this :
[Android DDMS (Monitor) does not start if user profile contains a space in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17424533/android-ddms-monitor-does-not-start-if-user-profile-contains-a-space-in-it)